# libobjc.A.dylib at objc_msgSend:15 crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

Anyone have any insight as to what is causing the following crash?

> CLASS:
>
> SIGNAL
>
> FILE:
>
> libobjc.A.dylib at objc_msgSend:15
>
> IOS:
>
> 5.1

```
0libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f7ef78 objc_msgSend 15
1libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f80175 _objc_rootRelease 36
2UIKit 0x3713542d -[UILayoutContainerView _endFastMode] 132
3UIKit 0x37135279 -[UILayoutContainerView setUseFastMode:] 68
4UIKit 0x37090129 -[UIView(FastModeAdditions) _setContainerLayoutViewForFastMode:] 104
5UIKit 0x36ef637b -[UIView dealloc] 574
6UIKit 0x371e0491 -[UIDropShadowView dealloc] 92
7libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f80175 _objc_rootRelease 36
8CoreFoundation 0x36b9c2e7 CFRelease 94
9CoreFoundation 0x36c18b37 __CFDictionaryStandardReleaseValue 70
10CoreFoundation 0x36c6c3bc __CFBasicHashDrain 264
11CoreFoundation 0x36b9c39b CFRelease 274
12libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f81e57 objc_release 38
13libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f80ead _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv 224
14libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f80dc9 _objc_autoreleasePoolPop 12
15CoreFoundation 0x36ba3cff _CFAutoreleasePoolPop 18
16CoreFoundation 0x36c262b3 __CFRunLoopRun 1274
17CoreFoundation 0x36ba94a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific 300
18CoreFoundation 0x36ba936d CFRunLoopRunInMode 104
19GraphicsServices 0x30c8b439 GSEventRunModal 136
20UIKit 0x36efae7d UIApplicationMain 1080
```

Comment: I would suspect you are releasing an object that is already released (implicitly within the autorelease pool).  You need to *enable zombies* and add breakpoints on `objc_exception_throw` etc.

Comment: Please see my answer and Slee's workaround at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146660/app-crashes-when-back-button-tapped-while-scrolling-table-view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect you are releasing an object that is already released (implicitly within the autorelease pool). You need to enable zombies and add breakpoints on `objc_exception_throw`, etc.

<sup>Source: [trojanfoe comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224908/libobjc-a-dylib-at-objc-msgsend15-crash/39113200#comment13135629_10224908)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This crash sounds like it happened in [UIKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/) while sending the message using `objc_msgSend` function (part of Objective-C).

You should compile your source code with the debug symbols and generate another more detailed backtrace. Use also debuggers such as dtrace/dtruss to further check problems with your code.

This could be a iOS bug with scrolling as mentioned in here: [App crashes when Back button tapped while scrolling table view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10146660/55075).

See also: [objc_msgSend](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/objc_msgsend.html) at ridiculousfish